# Особый или особенный

Tags: выбор-слова, синонимы

Особый:

> 1) а) Необычный, исключительный в каком-л. отношении.
>   б) Не похожий на других; своеобразный.
>   в) Отличный от других по степени проявления; значительный.
>   2) Отдельный, особый

Особенный:

> 1) а) Необычный, исключительный. б) Не похожий на других; своеобразный. в) Отличный от других по степени проявления; заметный, значительный. 2) а) Отдельный, отличный от других. б) Специально для кого-л., для какой-л. цели предназначенный.

Источник: словарь Ефремова

Это почти идентичные дефиниции. Есть ли какая-то разница между этими словами?

Comment: Употребление слова "особенный" в смысле "отдельный" (2а) или "специально предназначенный для чего-либо" (2б) является устаревшим. В этих случаях сейчас уместно употреблять только слово "особый". В этом, в общем-то, и заключается вся разница.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти слова сильно различаются по области употребления.

"Особенный" относят, как правило, к индивидуальным сущностям (конкретный человек, предмет и т.п.) и это слово имеет субъективный, оценочный или эмоциональный оттенок.

```
Этот артист в театре особенный, он мне интереснее прочих.
```

"Особый" чаще всего указывает не на индивидуальные свойства предмета или явления, а на его классификационную принадлежность, отличающую его от предмета (явления) другой группы по каким-то признакам. Используется (в отличие от слова "особенный") для образования формальных понятий (включая связанные с организационным "обособлением") :

```
особый класс млекопитающих, особый вид сварки, особый отдел, 

особый случай, особо тяжкие преступления, особые полномочия и т.п.
```

Answer (score 1):

Разница есть.
 "Особый" - отдельный. Например: Особый отдел в оранизации, как правило секретный, с ограниченным доступом.
 "Особенный" - отличающийся от других. Например: "У ней особенная стать".

Comment: Не только. "Особое мнение" - как раз "мнение, отличающееся от других".

Comment: Не согласен. Каждое из мнений отличается от других, но особое мнение подразумевает отгораживание от всех прочих мнений по принципиальным разногласиям. Обособляется от них своей системой базовых ценностей, к примеру.